# Builder::XmlMarkup/Nokogiri: make element with spaces between words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have to make XML request to external service and this service requires to send element:

```
 <foo bar></foo bar>
```

I am using Builder::XmlMarkup with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.20. Is it possible to create that kind of element with Builder::XmlMarkup or Nokogiri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would have to underscore them such as

```
<foo_bar></foo_bar>
```

XML expects element names to be a single string. So your example violates this syntax.

From w3:

```
XML Naming Rules
XML elements must follow these naming rules:
Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
Names cannot contain spaces

Any name can be used, no words are reserved.
```

If the second item is an attribute then you could use something like

```
<foo bar="baz"></foo>
```

Comment: But the external service doesn't understand the xml when I have foo_bar

Comment: @TsvetelinaBorisova then it is not valid XML. I don't know how else to help unless the second item is an attribute.